# Align PageController to the left without resizing

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi is there a way to somewhat "force" align the PageController to the left? What I want is to have it **aligned** to the **left** like the Exlore Categories without actually resizing the card

other options is to make it start in the 2nd card but I don't know how to do this one but I've tried changing initialPage to 1 to no avail

what I tried so far:

adjust the `viewportFraction` but this resizes the card
- Using `Align` widget with Alignment set to left -nothing

my code looks like this:

```
PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.75, );

//few more codes here

//cards
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _pageController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
        double value = 1;
        if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = _pageController.page - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * 0.3)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }

        return Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Padding(
              padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: widget,
              ),
            ),
          );
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set your `initialPage` state in `initState`

```
PageController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: 0.75);
  }
```